# I'm trying to make each button increase the numbers in the input in his own div but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make each button increase the numbers in the input in his own div but doesn't work.

```js
var c = 0;
$(".up").click(function() {
  var vote = document.getElementById('vote');
  $(vote).find(".counter").val(c);
  c++;
});
$(".down").click(function() {
  var vote = document.getElementById('vote');
  $(vote).find(".counter").val(c);
  c = c - 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="votewrap">
  <div id="vote">
    <button class="up">up</button>
    <input class="counter">
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
  <div id="vote">
    <button class="up">up</button>
    <input class="counter">
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to div id class that are the same, it will think that it is using only one

Comment: you cannot have multiple elements with same id, that is what class is for. then you have only one 'c' variable which both buttons are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To group multiple elements, use `class` property.

Your code seemed to had multiple errors, I've resolved them by using [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) methods!

```js
$(".up").click(function() {
  var vote = $(this).closest('.vote'); // find the closest div
  var c = $(this).siblings('.counter').val(); // get current value
  $(vote).find(".counter").val(++c); // increment and set again
});
$(".down").click(function() {
  var vote = $(this).closest('.vote'); // find the closest div
  var c = $(this).siblings('.counter').val(); // get current value
  $(vote).find(".counter").val(--c); // decrement and set again
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="votewrap">
  <div class="vote"> <!-- use class instead of id -->
    <button class="up" id='1'>up</button>
    <input class="counter" value='0'> <!-- Set initial value to 0 -->
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="vote"> <!-- use class instead of id -->
    <button class="up" id='2'>up</button>
    <input class="counter" value='0'> <!-- Set initial value to 0 -->
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `id` should be unique per page, so you should only have one. The `getElementById` method is returning the first value of vote that it finds since it's only expecting one.

Comment: i know but if i want more than button have the same variables do the same function what should i do

Answer (score 0):

I've added a few modifications to your code to separate the two fields. I did it a bit of a long way just to help with understanding. I gave your elements each an id to make them all unique from one another. I also moved your calculations up in your click handlers so you don't get the weird add/subtract behavior.

```js
var c1 = 0;
$("#up1").click(function() {
  var vote1 = document.getElementById('vote1');
  c1++;
  $(vote1).find("#counter1").val(c1);  
});
$("#down1").click(function() {
  var vote1 = document.getElementById('vote1');
  c1 = c1 - 1;
  $(vote1).find("#counter1").val(c1);
});

var c2 = 0;
$("#up2").click(function() {
  var vote2 = document.getElementById('vote2');
  c2++;
  $(vote2).find("#counter2").val(c2);
});
$("#down2").click(function() {
  var vote2 = document.getElementById('vote2');
  c2 = c2 - 1;
  $(vote2).find("#counter2").val(c2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="votewrap">
  <div id="vote1">
    <button id="up1">up</button>
    <input id="counter1">
    <button id="down1">down</button>
  </div>
  <div id="vote2">
    <button id="up2">up</button>
    <input id="counter2">
    <button id="down2">down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```